# How to get Spark service hostname programatically?

Tags: apache-spark

Is there any way to get Spark service hostname programatically (in my case I need to know Spark History Server hostname)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something around these lines:

```scala
// Try local IP
// According to goo.gl/LC6R3r
Try(sys.env("SPARK_LOCAL_IP"))
 // Fallback to web UI host
 .recoverWith { case _ => Try(sc.uiWebUrl.map(new java.net.URL(_).getHost).get) }
 // If both failed get local host name
 .getOrElse { java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName() }
```

Comment: Thanks, but SPARK_LOCAL_IP can be empty